# How can I tell Ubuntu GNOME to hibernate if the battery runs down completely?

Tags: gnome, hibernate

Currently my Ubuntu GNOME system just turns off the computer at zero power.

How can I set up hibernation in that case instead?

Comment: Hibernation in Ubuntu is very buggy, and hence is disabled by default. I would not recommend using it.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is a good question, so +1